# Ad network for Chromecast app

Tags: google-cast

My Chromecast app isn't for video but rather shows an information flow (sorry to be vague). I want the app to be free and monetized by occasional and/or banner onscreen ads, on the TV not the mobile device. In order to do this I need an ad network (AdWords, etc.) that has a fit for the display-only, full screen, non-clickable, nature of Chromecast but has a JavaScript/REST/etc. API that I can use from browser on the Chromecast device. Anyone have a suggestion? Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check Vistar Media.  They have ads that play on TVs you see in public spaces such as Hotel Lobbies. You would need to probably have significant volume.  I think Brightroll might have some media as well.  You could potentially run video ads from someone like Virool.

Comment: Virool is interesting! Of course this app doesn't fit nicely into any of their publishing categories, but worth talking to them. Thanks John